# Creating a folder with a content type using PowerShell/CSOM with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I need to create a folder in a document library (SPO) via PowerShell/SPO.

The code below creates the folder, but I can't figure out how to set the content type of the folder I just created. I created a content type based on Folder, and it works when I use it through the UI.

When I run the code below, it creates the folder then gets "Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder" when trying to set $Folder["ContentTypeId"].  What do I need to do to be able to set this?

```
$SiteURL = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/Accounting"
$LibraryName = "AR Files"
$FolderName = "Test"
$ContentType = "AR Folder"

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

# Find the ID of the content type
$Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web)
$Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web.ContentTypes)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($cc in $Ctx.Web.ContentTypes)
{
    if ($cc.Name -eq $ContentType)
    {
        $CTID = $cc.ID
    }
}

# Create folder
$fullname = $LibraryName + "/" + $FolderName
$Folder = $Ctx.Web.Folders.Add($fullname)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Load the folder just created
$Ctx.Load($Folder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Set the content type
$Folder["ContentTypeId"] = $CTID
$Folder.Update()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the `ListItem` of the created folder and set the Content Type on that.

Answer (score 2):

As Nadeem mentioned, you need to get the folder ListItem and then update it. It resides in the `ListItemAllFields` property of a folder.

To update the content type or for that matter, any other field of the Folder, you can use the below code:

```
# Load the folder just created
$Ctx.Load($Folder)
$Ctx.Load($Folder.ListItemAllFields)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$folderItem = $Folder.ListItemAllFields

$folderItem["ContentTypeId"] = $CTID
# $folderItem["Title"] = "New Test"
$folderItem.Update();
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Loading ListItemAllFields was the key.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help ! If it solved your issue, could you please mark it answer ? Its just a tick besides the answer :)

Comment: Yep I did mark it.